# URL that has a space in it and is not being recognized in Ektron Redirect module

Tags: asp.net, redirect, ektron

I am working on Ektron 8.6 website. And I had created few URL redirects on Ektron.

All redirects are working as expected except one.

The following is not working for me

```
Site:              Default
Redirect Code:     301- Moved Permanently
Original URL: /    uploadedFiles/TheHistory%20(2).pdf
New URL:           /test/The-History/
```

I am getting a `404 Page not found` error for

```
url : http://www.example.com/uploadedFiles/TheHistory%20(2).pdf
```

Did any one have any suggestions on the same ?

Comment: This comes up as a 404 for me as well. I wonder if it has something to do with the order in the web.config file of the handlers. I don't think this doesn't work for files at all.

Comment: @MichaelPeppler i had done a workaround by using http redirect module -something like manual redirecting. I know it's worst but it works for me. :)